# Running psexec on Windows Server 2008 R2 from Windows 7

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, batch-file

I'm trying to successfully run a batch file located on a server pc (Windows Server 2008 R2) from my Windows 7 client PC. But its not working and the command prompt shows the following error information message.

When I run

```
psexec \\199.219.21.141 -u admin /c "C:\Compile.bat"
```

I'm prompted for password, and when I enter the password and press I get

```
Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on 199.219.21.141
```

The user admin is part of the Local administrators on the server machine

Things I tried,

1. Turning off the UAC.
2. Turning OFF the Windows Firewall
3. Setting the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy DWORD to 1 in, HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
4. Caching the user credentials using
   cmdkey.exe /add:MACHINE_NAME_HERE /user:199.219.21.141\admin /pass:PASSWORD_HERE psexec.exe \199.219.21.141 -i notepad cmdkey.exe /delete:199.219.21.141

   Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on 199.219.21.141

The admin$ share is present on the server I can see my username listed as a part of administrators group. But I'm not able to open the share even using explorer

When I run the Run-->cmd.exe(admin mode)-->
\199.219.21.141\admin$

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?